# How can I set audience with OpenIdConnectMiddleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect, auth0

I am using the `OpenIdConnectMiddleware` in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 app, with Auth0 as authentication.

I have followed [this guide](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-core/v2/02-storing-tokens) to implement authentication via Auth0, and can successfully log in.

Now I want to use the retrieved access token to access a separate API; for this to work I need to include an `audience` parameter when authorizing with Auth0, [as described here](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/access-token#how-to-use-an-access-token).

Since the OpenID Connect middleware handles the authorization with Auth0, and there is no `Audience` setting on the `OpenIdConnectOptions`, how can I specify the `audience` parameter that should be passed to the `/authorize` endpoint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer in [this blog post from Jerrie Pelser](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/adding-parameters-to-openid-connect-authorization-url/). I need to use the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event handler to set `audience`:

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents {
    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context => {
        context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("audience", "https://my/api");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    ...
}
```